# jQuery array printing table

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html-table

I have an array (encoded in JSON) in jQuery. Let's say the array is `item1 : item1, item2 : item2, item3 : item3`. I need to loop through the results and print a table. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<table>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = {key1: "val1", key2: "val2"};
    for (var key in data) {
       $('table').append('<tr><td>' + data[key] + '</td></tr>');
    }
</script>
```